# Stupidly simple algebra help for some programming

Tags: math

I'm coding a "wind" thing for a game where if you run a certain wind command, it blows people away in a radius around you.

```
x is the maximum distance a player can be from the wind source
y is the actual distance a player is from the source of the wind
z is some number between 0 and 10 where if the player is
right next to the wind source z would equal 0 and if
the player is 30 blocks away it would equal 10.
15 blocks away would make z = 5, etc.

x = 30
z = y / x * 10
```

all this works fine, but I need the z to be opposite. I need z to be 10 when the player is near and 0 when the player is at 30 blocks. 15 blocks away should be 5, etc

My math is failing me on how I can invert these numbers in an easy fashion

Comment: Your current formula is doing exactly that.The bigger is `y` the bigger is `z`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does

```
z=(1-y/x)*10
```

work for you?

Comment: It's perfect, I knew it was simple. Thank you!